# Git workflow suggestion

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-workflow

I have a private repo on github and have about 7 developers working actively on it. My repo is branched as follows

```
  - devel
  - developerA-branch
  - developerB-branch and so on
```

What is happening now is each developer checks into his local branch, pushes to his remote and to devel.

What I want to achieve is

1. Create a sandbox branch
2. Once a developer pushes to his remote branch automatically pull it to sandbox and run tests.
3. If tests are good the push to devel
4. if tests are bad the revert the last set of changes and notify developers

This way only working and tested code ends up in devel. 
I understand that I may get into a scenario that if 2 developers commit to branch A and B and I pull both to sandbox and if tests fail I wouldn't know which one fails.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is quite broad subject, but start by looking at Git hooks, more specifically [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up building a series of git hooks to achieve this. thanks for the pointer.